# HighCharts with options

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I currently have a working chart using this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: graphURL,
    data: "",
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        //alert(response);
        jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
        if(jsonData != '' && jsonData != null) {
            var category = jsonData.XData.split(",");
            var series = jsonData.YData.split(",");
            series = $.each(series, function (i, amt) {
                series[i] = parseFloat(series[i]);
            });
            //Display chart
            UserChart(series, category, jsonData.YAxisTitle);
        }
    }
});
```

... but it doesn't allow me to set options like if I wanted an `area` chart instead of line etc.. how do I modify the code so I could include something like the following which I see in all examples:

```
chart : {
    renderTo : 'container'
},

rangeSelector : {
    selected : 1
},

title : {
    text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
},

series : [{
    name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
    data : data,
    type : 'area',
    threshold : null,
    tooltip : {
        valueDecimals : 2
    },
    fillColor : {
        linearGradient : {
            x1: 0, 
            y1: 0, 
            x2: 0, 
            y2: 1
        },
        stops : [[0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]], [1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']]
    }
}]
```

Comment: Can you show `UserChart` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `series` is the series points' data.
Try to pass a serie to `UserChart`.
Like the following:

```
var points = jsonData.YData.split(",");
points = $.each(series, function (i, amt) {
    points[i] = parseFloat(series[i]);
});

// here you set your serie config
var serie = {
    name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
    type: 'area',
    data: points,
    threshold : null,
    tooltip : {
        valueDecimals : 2
    }
};

UserChart(serie, category, jsonData.YAxisTitle);
```

Then in `UserChart` you should add the serie directly to the chart series.

**Example**:

```
var options: {
    chart : {
        renderTo : 'container'
    },

    rangeSelector : {
        selected : 1
    },

    title : {
        text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },

    series : []
};

function UserChart(serie, category, jsonData.YAxisTitle) {
    options.series.push(serie);
    // add your code
}
```